# Google Search Appliance - clarification for Query Suggestions saving for "90 Days"

Tags: google-search-appliance

The GSA documentation on Query Suggestions says "The search appliance automatically refreshes query suggestions every 24 hours and keeps them for 90 days."
Does anyone know what the 90 days really means?

- If the suggestions are refreshed every 24 hours, will that 90 day timer reset every time?
- Is the 90 day referring to the time a search was run by a user that
  resulted in the creation of the query suggestion? And what if another
  user later on "used" the query suggestion - does it effectively reset
  the expiration date?
- Can I adjust the length of the expiration?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, query suggestions are composed of queries that have been executed in the last 90 days.  Therefore, if you search for something on day 1 and day 89, the term would be present for longer than 90 days.

I know of no way to extend this 90 days.  However, it also has a positive benefit - things that people are no longer search for will no longer appear as suggestions.